# How to check if a mouse is over a control

Tags: c++, controls, winapi, ismouseover

How does one check if the mouse is over a certain HWND? I have tried using the WM_MOUSELEAVE and WM_MOUSEMOVE messages to keep track, but if you click a button and drag the mouse out of the button, it doesn't receive the WM_MOUSELEAVE until the mouse is released, which is too late, because:

When you click a button, the WM_COMMAND message is only sent if:
1. The mouse was originally depressed over the button
2. The mouse is over the button
3. The mouse is released over the button

I need to replicate this functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To duplicate this functionality, just call `SetCapture()` so that mouse messages are sent to your window even if the mouse leaves it. You can read the current mouse position as it moves and determine if it is still over your window/button (I'm still not 100% sure what you are doing). And, when the mouse button is released, you can call `ReleaseCapture()` to restore where mouse messages are sent.

**EDIT:** Oh, and you can use the Windows API function `WindowFromPoint()` to determine which window the mouse is over.

Comment: setCapture is not a valid solution because multiple buttons need to know at the same time. I'm pretty sure also that SetCapture is not how the Button class's WndProc does it, which is what I need to emulate.

Comment: Well, it's valid, even though it won't work in your case due to a restriction that you didn't mention. Oh, and I can guarantee you that the Windows button control uses SetCapture(). I've duplicated this functionality a number of times.

Comment: @Jonathan, thanks, and please see my question to Hans Passant.

Comment: @John: Windows doesn't support selecting multiple buttons at the same time. I again guarantee that Windows buttons use SetCapture(). That's how they know to redraw themselves as the mouse moves over and away from the button while the mouse button is held down.

Comment: If you have two buttons, which one do you call SetCapture on? Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: The one the mouse button is pressed down over. That's what Windows does. If you want to do something different from what Windows does, you need to be more explicit.

Comment: Ok, I thought you call setCapture before any event happened to the button. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is built-in to Windows, it is called 'mouse capture', SetCapture(hWnd).  It ensures you get mouse messages even though the mouse has moved outside of the window.  You call it on the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message notification.

Comment: I don't care if I get mouse messages outside the window.

Comment: If you don't care about the button-up message then don't call SetCapture().  Which is odd, it tends to be important to show the button no longer pressed.  This tends to be taken care of without any hassle by class libraries.  Even the native Windows BUTTON class does this.

Comment: @Hans so BUTTON uses SetCapture? How do multiple buttons work at once?

Comment: Not quite sure, do you have an example of a UI that lets you click more than one button at the same time?

Comment: SetCapture takes an HWND. How do multiple buttons function at once if you must specify one HWND?

Comment: You haven't answered my previous comment.  I've just never seen any UI where clicking more than one button with *one* mouse click ever worked.  Or made sense to the user.

Comment: I misphrased my question. If there are two buttons which need to be monitored, how would one use setCapture?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many buttons are there.  You start paying attention when you see the mouse down notification on *one* of them.  Indicating that the user clicked on *one* button.  Capture the mouse.  Now look at the mouse up message.  Still on that same button?  Click.  Avoid re-inventing this.

Comment: Ok, and would it be good enough to use GetWindowFromPoint to see if its the same HWND in the mournful up event?

Comment: No, you know that the coordinates are relative from the button control, you captured the mouse after all.  They are always relative from the button control.  All you have to do is check >= 0 && < size.  The answer you selected is the only mournful bit here.

Comment: Thanks, but what does the "mournful" part mean?