# Mouse hover effect for owner drawn button without subclassing

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi, ownerdrawn

As the title suggests, is there a way to receive in the parent window a notification of mouse hovering a button (which has been owner drawn) without the need of subclassing it? I use plain C on Windows.

I don't use custom drawing or any other types than owner draw (already tried).

I would like to change the appearance of the button when the mouse hovers it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subclassing a button: right messages handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652919/subclassing-a-button-right-messages-handling)

Comment: Surely if you have a button it will proccess messages? Such as the [WM_MOUSEHOVER message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645613%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: @WeatherVane the `WM_MOUSEHOVER` message is posted after a prior call to `TrackMouseEvent` and to the window which you decide to track. Since I don't plan to subclass, I can't call `TrackMouseEvent` I think...

Comment: Here [another suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495275/how-to-check-if-a-mouse-is-over-a-control)

Comment: Thanks, that helps! I will try that suggestion ;)

Comment: *As the title suggests, is there a way to receive **in the parent window** a notification of mouse hovering a button (which has been owner drawn) without the need of subclassing it?* Handle `WM_SETCURSOR`. Do not change anything, just detect if wParam is HWND of your button. If it is, then set a flag (some BOOL) and InvalidateRect(..) your button. Just a thought... Perhaps other members can offer better solution...